# ApiController method with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, ajax, http-get, asp.net-apicontroller

It is unclear from here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2
how to use multiple parameters with ApiController method and what is the URL to call it as well. Any clue?

**C#**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/workorders")]
    public class WorkOrdersController : ApiController
    {
            [Route("WorkOrdersByDates")]
            [HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<WorkOrderItemView> GetWorkOrdersByDates(string startDate, string endDate)
            {
                var r = new List<WorkOrderItemView>();
                //
                return r;
            }
    }
```

**AJAX**

```
 var startDate = $('#StartDate').val();
            var endDate = $('#EndDate').val();

            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "api/workorders/WorkOrdersByDates",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ startDate: "' + endDate + '", endDate: "' + endDate + '" }),
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result.Result);
                    }
                });
```

**Global.asax**

```
  protected void Application_Start()
        {


            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
                );


            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `JSON.stringify` for those parameters, just give it the raw object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `JSON.stringify` for those parameters as that will pass a string to the `data` parameter, just give it the raw object itself and let jQuery convert them to a query string.

```
var startDate = $('#StartDate').val();
var endDate = $('#EndDate').val();

$.ajax(
    {
        url: "api/workorders/WorkOrdersByDates",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { startDate: "' + endDate + '", endDate: "' + endDate + '" },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.Result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't stringify the data in the ajax caller.  This should work:

```
 var startDate = $('#StartDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#EndDate').val();

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "api/workorders/WorkOrdersByDates",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: { 
                    startDate: startDate.toISOString(), 
                    endDate: endDate.toISOString()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.Result);
                }
            });
```

(also note that I use `toISOString()` on JavaScript date values when the controller is expecting `DateTime` types - this gives consistent conversions as long as the JavaScript object is actually a date value - alternatively you can leave your controller types as `string` and drop that `toISOString()`, but I find the ISO conversion very helpful)

Answer (score -2):

you Ajax method you are passing the parameter throw the "data" param, however your api is using "HttpGet".
To correct way to make ajax call using "Get" you shold pass the param in the URL.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "api/workorders/WorkOrdersByDates?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate,
        type: "GET"...
```

Comment: While that's one way to do it, it's not required.  Get and data param works just fine.

Comment: jQuery will convert a `data` to query string for a GET